# jQuery display:none child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, this

I have a 3D flip animation on an div container element. It works with a hover function.
This element have 2 main child containers : **front** and **back**.

Inside the front and back container there are a child div container where there are a picture.

```
<div class="element hover blog" id="_13" >
<div class="front shadow">
<div class="element-image-front"><div class="overlay"></div>
<img src="./Post thumbnail images/formlabs.jpg"/>
</div></div>
<div class="back">
<div class="element-image-back">
<img src="./Post thumbnail images/formlabs.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In my css the back container and back img container are display none.

I want to display block the back container and img container on hover fonction. And to display none when the mouse is not on hover.

I Have a problem to correctly write the code with $(this). 
My script works fine, howerver I want to only display the back and the img back of the element hover.
Because I have many element on the same page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hover').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('flip');
        $('.element-image-back img').css('display', 'block');
        $('.back').css('display', 'block');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('flip');
        $('.hover').$('.element-image-back img').css('display', 'none');
        $('.hover').$('.back').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

My css:

```
.element {
cursor: pointer;
width: 250px;
height: 180px;
margin: 3px;
float: left;
overflow: visible;
position: relative;
}
.element-image-front img{
position:absolute;
z-index: 3;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
overflow:hidden;
}
.element-image-back img{
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 4;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
opacity: 0.035;
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.element .front {
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 900;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;   
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #333;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.element.flip .front {
position: absolute;
z-index: 900;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #333;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.element .back {
position: absolute;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 800;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #434343;        
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.element.flip .back {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #434343; /***#191919***/
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.click .front {
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.click.flip .front {
-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.click .back {
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.click.flip .back {
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

EDIT: here a fiddle with css :hover :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9B5mS/

The is still a problem with the animation with css :hover ....

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery chaining is wrong in `$('.hover').$('.element-image-back img')`:
Try to alter your code like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.hover').hover(function () {
           $(this).addClass('flip');
           $('.element-image-back img').css('display', 'block');
           $('.back').css('display', 'block');
       }, function () {
           $(this).removeClass('flip');
           $('.element-image-back img').css('display', 'none');
           $('.back').css('display', 'none');
       });
   });
```

Comment: Your "flip" is in a class. You either add it to the element ".hover" or remove it. See if you want this class indeed to be added to this element and perhaps post the css here.